# Wordpress AJAX call keeps returning 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My AJAX call returns 0.
Here is the jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action:"add_social_share_entry",
                referral_code: "<?php echo Contest_Domination::get_referral_code("",""); ?>"
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }, error: function(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

And the PHP.

```
function add_social_share_entry(){
    $referral_code = $_REQUEST["referral_code"];
    if ( class_exists( 'Contest_Domination' ) ) {
        if (!empty($referral_code)) {
            $referral_submission = Contest_Domination::get_submission_by_referral_code($referral_code);
            if($referral_submission!==false){
                $referral_id = $referral_submission->submission_ID;
                Contest_Domination::add_entries($referral_id, 1);
                echo "Successfully added entry";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Referral code not received";
        }                           
    }else{
        echo "Class does not exist";
    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_add_social_share_entry', 'add_social_share_entry');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_social_share_entry', 'add_social_share_entry');
```

These are both on the same page (a template page), and the response is 0. Let me know if you need additional information or request headers. This is stupefying me. Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** I realized I might have been a bit ambiguous. The JS and PHP are both in a PHP template file, so the PHP bit runs fine. I'll show my headers so it isn't thought that the error is coming from there.

> action:add_social_share_entry
>   referral_code:552ec562300af

---

**SOLUTION**
As Lukas pointed out below, I needed to move the WP AJAX hooks into my `functions.php` file in my theme because it wasn't working within my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try moving your PHP part

```
function add_social_share_entry() {
.....
}
add_action('wp_ajax_add_social_share_entry', 'add_social_share_entry');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_social_share_entry', 'add_social_share_entry');
```

to your WordPress functions.php theme file? I guess WordPress doesn't register that hooks if you have placed them in template.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Worked the second I moved it to `functions.php`

Comment: Or just include the file to functions.php, it can work as well

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are mixing javascript with php in the wrong way, first:

```
referral_code: "<?php echo Contest_Domination::get_referral_code("",""); ?>"
```

That will never work, unless you are rendering your javascript file via PHP, which i suppose you dont.

Having this on hand, you can tell where your code is ending:

```
die();
```

You are sending nothing back to your jquery success/errro callbacks.

I recommend you check on how you are getting the referral code, and once you've got it and send it to your PHP, use some headers with status code and response text so you can tell your jquery ajax when it should call error and when it should call success.

## EDIT

Try removing the `die();` from your function, that is killing the script execution and might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated post. You'll see the issue isn't the PHP. It's sending fine and getting a 200 OK response from /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php so I think it must be something about either the template file not having access to add actions to WP, or an issue with the template file and the admin-ajax.php file located in the wp-admin folder.